# Angular 6 ngrx store testing: cannot read ids of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ngrx

I'm trying to test a component which has injected a Store. The test does not pass and gives me the following error: "Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined"

Test:

```
 const initialState = {
    quoteInfo: {
        quoteLoaded: true,
        ids: [0],
        entities: {
            '0': {
                id: 0,
                quoteId: 'string',
                quoteStatus: 0,
                reference: 'ref01',
            }
        }
    },
    quoteSettings: {
        quoteSettingsReceived: true,
        ids: [1],
        entities: {
          '1': {
            id: 1,
            status: 0,
            customer: 'string',
            customerId: 'cus01',
            carrier: 'car01',
            contact: 'contact01',
            contactId: 'c01',
            priceCategory: 'vip',
            priceCategoryId: 'pr1',
            creationDate: null,
            expirationDate: null,
            deliveryDate: null,
            currency: null,
            currencyId: null,
            paymentDescription: 'pay desc',
            tax: 0,
            comments: 'comments',
            shippingAddress: null,
            billingAddress: null
          }
        }
    }
  };
```

Test beforeEach:

```
  beforeEach( async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [GeneralComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({ feature: combineReducers({quoteSettings: settingsReducer, quoteInfo: infoReducer }, initialState)}),
      ],
      providers: [
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

The error appears in component initialization which code is the following:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.randomObservable$ = this._store.pipe(select(randomSelector));
  }
```

Random Selector

```
export const randomFeatureSelector= createFeatureSelector<RandomState>('random');
export const randomSelector = createSelector(
  randomFeatureSelector, // this is null
  fromRandomReducer.selectAll
);
```

Comment: You need to provide randomSelector code as well

Comment: The problem is not with the selector itself. The problem is that what is received by selector is undefined. Check code edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the html file were I was using the observable from the selector directly and if the store is still not initialized, it gives that error

Comment: How did you solve it? I don't know why the component initialises before the store does.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: In my case, the error was in the test. My selector was using several feature stores and I only had one store initialised. Because of this, when it tried to "join" data between both stores, one of them was undefined. Hope it helps

Comment: I am facing i think similar issue with feature store, do you have any code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

For mocking Store I usually use BehaviorSubject from rx.js:

```
let mockStore;
beforeEach( async(() => {
 mockStore = new BehaviorSubject(initialState);
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [GeneralComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
  {provide: Store, useValue: mockStore}
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```

}));

...